# What is the meaning of "if" in "If in the past the protests erupted against the continuing military rule…"?

Tags: meaning

Is the usage of **If** correct in the following sentence?

> **If** in the past the protests erupted against the continuing military rule, in February, the military usurped power from an elected government after a decade of partial democracy.

If it is correct what is its meaning?

Source: [The Hindu](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/mayhem-in-myanmar-on-the-violence-during-myanmars-armed-forces-day/article34257174.ece?homepage=true)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little odd, but unless I was reading very carefully I'd skim over it.  I think the meaning of the sentence is clear.

The word "if" can be used synonymously with "although"

> (How do you feel after the marathon?) I feel good, if a little stiff.

I think this sense is what the author was aiming for.  I would have used "Whereas"

The author is constrasting "the past" (in which there were protests against the military) with February, (in which the military staged a coup)